# Read .txt file in shiny app with data after some text lines

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am developing a shiny app, in which I need to upload .txt data files.
But the data files that I have contents not only (x,y) values but some text is included in the initial 14 lines. 15th line is empty and actual data starts from the 16th line.

When I upload .txt file on my shiny app, I want the app to ignore the initial 15 lines and start reading the data from the 16th line.

Here is how the data looks like in .txt file:

```
Profiles of file: D:\Results_CWL\NEXPERIA\PCB ohne Tim\passiver Zyklus\Linien\5\20200717_123553\025\Default0000.frt
xrange = [0,000000000000 m, 0,180100000000 m]
xsize = 0,180100000000 m
yrange = - 
ysize = -
zrange = [-0,00185947345285 m, 0,00107671234384 m ]
zsize = 0,00293618579669 m
xpoints = 3603
ypoints = 1
- end of header -
Profile 4       
x [m]   z [m]   
x0 = 0,209759995341 y0=0,205091997981   
x1 = 0,389860004187 y1=0,205091997981   

0,000000000000  -0,00123933734030   
5,00000000000E-005  -0,000973215937665  
0,000100000000000   -0,000590819013931  
0,000150000000000   -0,000274342070665  
0,000200000000000   -9,06206436190E-005 
0,000250000000000   -2,28695525823E-005 
0,000300000000000   -4,86363199146E-006 
0,000350000000000   -2,42215123338E-006 
0,000400000000000   1,85044009326E-006  
0,000450000000000   7,64895689370E-006  
0,000500000000000   1,40578438837E-005  
0,000550000000000   1,92459904946E-005  
0,000600000000000   2,32133967265E-005  
0,000650000000000   2,47393222003E-005  
0,000700000000000   2,53496923898E-005  
0,000750000000000   2,50445072950E-005  
0,000800000000000   2,44341371055E-005
```

Every data file that I have is in the same format.

My attempt to read the data file without any extra text:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df <- read.table(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
    return(df)
  })
```

Suggest me some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `skip` option in `read.table`, to specify the number of lines of the data file to skip before beginning to read data.

```
read.table(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], skip = 15, sep = ......)
```

Comment: Is there any way to skip the rows if the cells are empty in those rows?